# How to customize wingpanel in elementary OS 0.4 Loki?

Tags: wingpanel, system

It is possible to do that 0.4 Loki?

In previous versions of elementary OS (Luna and Freya) I remember it was possible; in the current version it seems not. At least in the [elementary update PPA](https://launchpad.net/~versable/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-update) there were a couple of packages to install "super wingpanel" and "wingpanel slim", modified versions of the "vanilla" one so users were offered with more variety. Any hints?

Comment: In Luna, was possible editing the file
`/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css`

and changing values under the lines .panel { and . panel-shadow {

See for details here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/customize-elementaryos-panel/

don't knowif it might wok in Loki

Comment: and to add some transparency to wingpanel and even slingshot:

http://eos-snippets.blogspot.it/2013/10/panel-transparency.html.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "customize".

As far as I can tell, the authors of those replacement panel projects have stopped development, so you probably won't be able to replace your panel with those dead projects.

Wingpanel still uses the `panel` css class and includes some new classes like `maximized` and `translucent`, so all of it's color changes are now handled in CSS and not hard-coded.

As always, all of the indicators are extensions for the panel and none of them are mandatory or hard-coded.